# Inequality for the autocorrelation of order $2$ for an $MA(4)$ process

Tags: inequality, time-series

> Suppose that $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ are nonnegative, I'm trying to prove that
>   $$
> \frac{x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_4}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\leq\frac{9}{10}
> $$
>   which is equivalent to
>   $$
> 9(1+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)-10(x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_4)\geq 0.\tag{i}
> $$
>   Unable to simplify the LHS of (i) (mostly because of not having "enough" of $x^2$), I split the problem into 2 cases: $x_1x_3\geq x_2x_4$ and $x_2x_4\geq x_1x_3$. I can prove (i) for the former but not the latter. Can you please help me? I hope I might see a handling of the case $x_2x_4\geq x_1x_3$ or a more elegant approach to the problem.

**More context**: you probably already recognize the LHS of the original inequality as the autocorrelation of order $2$ for the $MA(4)$ process $Y_t=(1+x_1L+x_2L^2+x_3L^3+x_4L^4)u_t$ where $u_t$ is white noise and $L$ as usual denotes the lag operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ 5(x_1^2+x_3^2)\geq 10 x_1 x_3, $$
so we just need to prove:
$$ 9(1+x_2^2+x_4^2)\geq 10 x_2(1+x_4). \tag{1}$$
We can regard both terms as functions of $x_2$ for a fixed $x_4$, so we just need to prove that
$$ 9(1+q^2)+9x^2 \geq 10(1+q) x \tag{2}$$
for any $x\geq 0$ (and any $q\geq 0$). This is a simple convexity inequality: the derivative of the LHS is $10(1+q)$ for $x=\frac{5}{9}(1+q)$, and the LHS is a convex function, hence we just need to check that $(2)$ holds for $x=\frac{5}{9}(1+q)$. The resulting inequality is equivalent to:
$$ 81(1+q^2)\geq 25(1+q)^2 \tag{3}$$
that is very easy to check.

Comment: I learned a neat trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: With the same argument it is also possible to improve the constant $\frac{9}{10}$ up to $\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}.$

Comment: @ jack: that's very cool. In class, we are actually given a formula to bound the $\rho(k)$ for an $MA(q)$ process: $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{\lfloor q/k\rfloor+2}\right)$. In this case, $q=4$ and $k=2$, the expression evaluates to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ which is just as you stated!